# react-native background blank flicks when loading different scenes

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working in a react-native app for both iOS/Android, I have the following structure in wix-navigation v2:

```
SplashScreenView (stack)
   |_> if user is logged in, starts tabBasedApp (stack)
   |_> if user is not logged in, goes to AuthView (stack)
```

My app background is green. So whenever I start the app (PROD/Release) I keep seeing the blank white flickering backgrounds before loading each scene. It looks pretty bad.

App starts = white loading like 1-2 seconds, then the SplashScreen goes into view, ends SplashScreen animation and then another flick because it's loading the next tabBased screen.

Is this a "RootView" issue? How can I fix this detail?

UPDATE: After adding this in the styles.xml the following color setup, it kinda worked but still whenever I open the app for the first time, there's 1 more blank stuck moment I cannot fix.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Once the app is opened and minimised, opened back again, that blank never happens again. What's the reason of that?

Answer (score 1):

It was a missconfuguration of react-native-splash-screen. After installing it properly and setting the correct styles.xml and colors.xml it worked.

If anyone is under the same circumstance, this is my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_gradient_bg</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_gradient_bg</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```